# How to create a form that populates a list in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jquery, rest

I need to create an HTML form with two text boxes and a button that you click the update button it inserts the two values ​​in a sharepoint list. Below an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
// Function to save data in SharePoint list
     PostFormBuilder.RESTPost = function (listTitle, query) {
        var execute = function (listTitle, query) {
            var restUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl +
                "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('" + listTitle + "')/items";
            if (query != "") {
                restUrl = restUrl + "?" + query;
            }
            var deferred = $.ajax({
                url: restUrl,
                method: "POST",
                body: { '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.TestListItem' }, 'Title': 'Test'},
                headers: {
                    Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                    "IF-MATCH": "*",
                    "X-Http-Method": "MERGE"
                }
            });

            return deferred.promise()
        };

        return {
            execute: execute
        }
    }();
```

I think the problem is in the ajax part but i dont know how fix. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, you may find using the SPServices javascript library easier to use.  Mark Anderson has done a fantastic job handling all the nuances involved when using client side code.  You can find the library [here](https://spservices.codeplex.com/) .  The function you would want to use is [UpdateListItems](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=UpdateListItems&referringTitle=Lists) and this [discussion thread](https://spservices.codeplex.com/discussions/245285) will show you what you need to do.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Keep in mind though that SPServices relies on a deprecated feature (SOAP services), so using the REST services sounds like a good idea moving forward.

Comment: As much as I like SPServices, it's not what this post is tagged with. It's tagged as a REST question and should be answered that way imo.  Christophe has a tiny library that wraps REST: sprest.codeplex.com

Comment: @iOnline247 thanks for the mention :-) ... but my SPrest library applies to SP 2010 REST, not the 2013 one.

Comment: Didn't know that... I'm a JSOM kind of guy. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The `body` property in your ajax call doesn't sound right. I think what you actually want is to pass a string as a `data` property.